# Get rid of the outer scroll bar

Tags: html, css

This is what I have now.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUKWL/10/)

I want to get rid of the outside scrollbar.
The css below causes the problem.

```
.west-contents, .east-contents {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    height:100%;
    height:-36px !important;
}
```

If I set the height to `90% - 95%` it will appear ok but if you resize the height you will notice that this is not the proper way to do it.

only `.west-contents, .east-contents` should have overflows.

**EDIT:**
The scroll bar's end must be in the **blue line**  not in the **red line**.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `overflow:hiddden;` in your `.main`

```
.main {
    width:100%;
    height:90%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

See the updated fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUKWL/6/)

Comment: Yeah this solves the issue but please see the updated question. This is not what I am looking for.

Comment: The end of the bottom scrollbar must be in the blue line, but if you check the demo, it ends in the red line. It's just not visible because the footer is on top of the scroll bar.

Comment: try to change the height to 88% to see what I mean.

Comment: Ya i understand wait for a while

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `overflow-y: hidden;` to `body, html`.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/denodir/cUKWL/8/)

Comment: @Adrian Applying overflow-y: hidden; to body, html will make it a global change for all your body tags. Other way to do this if you are using jquery apply it via script on run time before that page is loaded in DOM.

Comment: @SunilKumar Thanks for mentioning that. You would also want to consider putting a div wrapper around the content, and apply `overflow:hidden` to it instead of to `body`.

Comment: Yeah this solves the issue but please see the updated question. This is not what I am looking for.